# White wiring for everything?

Tags: electrical, wiring, neutral

I'm converting a shed to a tiny house. I'm disabled and I don't have a lot of money. My neighbor gave me 350 feet of neutral white. 12×32 is the space. My question is, may I re-task it to be used for the entire project. It would help me out a lot. As long as I tag it well and identify each for its new task. Will this work? And possibly pass  an inspection?

Comment: Is it a single white wire or a white cable containing wires?

Comment: If you are using individual wires, (not cables) you will need to put them in conduit. While I'm a huge fan of conduit (having seen too much rodent nibbled NM cable in my time) the conduit (and other wire colors you need) will probably exceed the cost of buying some NM cable suited to your loads.

Comment: "I have the wrong wire, help me use it anyway" common question.   Trade it on Craigslist or Facebook Marketplace for the right wire.  Notably, individual wires need to be run in conduit, and conduit is expensive.  Make sure you are aware of a) the Habitat for Humanity Store, and b) actual Habitat for Humanity, the charity that helps people with little money.  Started by president Jimmy Carter, so it helps to not hate him.

Comment: Are Americans allowed to use plastic conduit? It's everywhere in EU and dirt cheap

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, that won't work. There technically isn't "neutral wire". You *might* be referring to "ground wire". But here's the deal - at least in US/Canada:

With individual wires and *most* of the time with 2 or 3 wire cable (note that "2 wire cable" or "/2" for short refers to black + white + bare ground (really 3 wires but only 2 "regular" wires) and "3 wire cable" or "/3" for short refers to black + white + red + bare ground):

- Black, red, blue, yellow, most other colors = hot, switched hot, travelers (3-way switches)
- White, gray = neutral
- Green, green/yellow (both colors on one wire) or bare (uninsulated) = ground

There are certain exceptions in *cables only* where white can be used as a hot wire by marking it with tape or paint (easiest is a circle of black electrical tape near each end). That lets you turn "white which is almost always neutral" into something else.

There are also exceptions for large wires, but for most people that only involves feeders for breaker panels - it doesn't help for normal 15A/20A/30A branch circuits.

That little trick doesn't work for anything else. You can strip a black or white or any other color wire of its insulation to use it as a bare ground wire, and that's easy enough to do if you just need a few inches.

Similarly, if you wrap the **entire length** of white wire with black (or red or whatever) tape you could turn it into a hot wire or wrap the entire length of a black wire with white tape to turn it into a neutral. I am not sure if that is legitimate under code or not, but I have seen it mentioned in some places. But it is not at all practical because electrical tape isn't free and if you are dealing with more than a foot or two it will take you a long time.

Would using white wire for everything "work"? Yes. But it would never pass inspection, not even close.

Comment: Thanks so much,  I'll go back to code. I want it to be right, and of safe. You taught me  a  great deal.....